# Is there a limit on outbound TCP connections through a EC2 NAT Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat

Our setup is as follows:
VPC (with about 30-50 ec2 instances) -> EC2 Nat Instance -> Internet.

Since Dec 13, we have been seeing issues where randomly the connection were starting to refuse. No such issue was seen earlier. Only change is the processing of the urls via API has increased (In other words more TCP connections are getting initiated & worked on). Requesting an API Request (POST/GET/PUT doesn't matter) from an EC2 instance within VPC via NAT Instance to the Internet is failing at random.

I tried logging the Flow logs, but in these flow logs, I see the entry where it shows ACCEPT OK for the TCP log transmission ( pic attached - https://ibb.co/dwe3X6 ). However, the same capture on tcpdump (one specific ec2 instance within vpc), shows the TCP Retransmission failure (where traffic is going through the NAT instance) ( pic attached - https://ibb.co/npqozm ). They are of the same time and same ec2 instance.

Basically, the SYN packet gets initiated, but then the actual handshake doesn't go through. Note, that this doesn't happen all the time.

The tcp retransmission failures are random. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. So this is leading me to believe there is some sort of a queue or buffer in NAT instance which is hitting the limit and I am not sure how to get to root of this.

Comment: missing your pictures ,,, - What is the size of the EC2 NAT instance ?

Comment: Maybe you can find some additional information in this thread; https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231806

Comment: @jarnohenneman Added the missing pictures. EC2 Nat size is t2.micro

Comment: If there was limit on *outbound* connections it wouldn't cause connection refusals. But you seem to be really talking about inbound connections.

Comment: The issue occurs at random when a url is requested from an EC2 instance inside the VPC to the url in Internet. So this is outbound connection per se.

Comment: Neverthess it still wouldn't cause connection refusals. It would cause 'permission denied' errors.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests a problem out on the Internet or at the distant end.

`ACCEPT` means the connection (the instantion of the flow) was allowed by the security group and network ACLs, telling you nothing about whether the handshake succeeded. `OK` in the flow logs means the log entry itself is intact.

There is no reason to believe that the NAT instance is limiting this, because the SYN packets are indeed shown in wireshark leaving the instance headed for the Internet and the flow log suggests that it is indeed making its way out of the NAT instance successfully.

You used the term "refuse" but the wireshark entries are consistent with a `Connection timed out` error, rather than `Connection refused`, which is an active refusal by the far end (or, less commonly, by an intermediate firewall) due to the lack of a listening service on the destination port, which would cause the destination to respond with a TCP `RST`.

If you can duplicate the problem with a [NAT Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html), then you can be confident that it is not in any way related to the NAT instance itself, which is simply a Linux instance using `iptables ... -j MASQUERADE`.

The only thing the network infrastructure throttles is outbound connections to destination port 25, because of spam.  Everything else is bounded only by the capabilities of the instance itself.  With a t2.micro, you should have (iirc) in excess of 125 Mbits/sec of Ethernet bandwidth available, and the NAT capability is not particularly processor intensive, so unless you are exhausting the Ethernet bandwidth or the CPU credit balance of the instance, it seems unlikely that the NAT instance could be the cause.

Comment: So late yesterday, I was able to connect with AWS Technical Support and it was confirmed on AWS end that AWS indeed does throttle network if it goes beyond certain limit (MB or packet counts or both). The limit wasn't specified, but it was clearly mentioned that I would have to upgrade my t2.micro NAT instance or shift to NAT gateway to prevent this throttling from happening. Ideal recommendation was to make use of NAT Gateway.

Comment: Well, of course, any network will "throttle" if you exceed its capacity in bandwidth or PPS... but remembering that AWS is *billing* you for traffic, it is counter-intuitive to expect them to expend resources on active throttling mechanisms that would effectively reduce what you would have to pay them.  Absent some information about your NAT instance's throughput in bytes and packets, your CPU utilization and credit balance, it is premature to conclusively say that such throttling explains the issue.  See what you find with the NAT Gateway.  Drinks are on me if the problem goes away.

Comment: Another thought, if you haven't tried it, would be to stop and then start the NAT instance via the EC2 API or console, which will move your instance to new hardware.  While unlikely, this might move you away from any network problem internal to the availability zone where the instance is running.

Comment: For now, i upgraded the NAT instance to next level t2.small and would see how it works out, so far no issues and connections are working as expected. But its odd to see the throttling been done on AWS end.